# How do I stop the IDE from referencing Windows-specific XML units in my non-Windows project?

Tags: android, xml, delphi

I want to create a Android program in Delphi XE5 to work with XML files. I use `TXMLDocument`.

I can't compile and run it, though, because Delphi repeatedly adds `Xml.Win.msxmldom` in the `uses` section. The following error occurs:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(11): F1026 File not found:
>   'C:\Users\HamiD\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Xml.Win.msxmldom.dcu'
>   (unit scope "Xml.Win" indicates Win32, Win64 only)

How do I avoid using that unit in my project?

Comment: Having <b>MS</b>XML on Android would be... eh... surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `TXMLDocument`, change the DOM vendor from `MSXML` to `ADOMXML v4`, to stop the need to use the `MSXML` unit.

This is covered in the documentation for [`TXMLDocument.DOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor). Although it mentions specifically Mac, the same applies to other FireMonkey applications on iOS and Android.

> Tip: If you are designing a FireMonkey application that is intended to run on Mac OS X, then you should perform the following steps to ensure that the compilation succeeds:
>
> Change DOMVendor from MSXML to ADOM XML v4.
>
> If the Xml.Win.msxmldom unit is in the uses clause then remove it.
>
> Compile your application for Mac OS X.

The documentation was modified in the [XE5 version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) to read instead:

> Tip: To use TXMLDocument in Mac OS X or Mobile applications, in the Object Inspector, set the DOMVendor property to ADOM XML v4 right after dropping this component onto the Form Designer. Otherwise, the TXMLDocument component is no longer usable for iOS/Android/OSX applications.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it does. The documentation was modified when XE5 was released to say "Tip: To use TXMLDocument in Mac OS X or Mobile applications, in the Object Inspector, set the DOMVendor property to ADOM XML v4 right after dropping this component onto the Form Designer. Otherwise, the TXMLDocument component is no longer usable for iOS/Android/OSX applications."

Comment: So you can import parse XML files and make objects from XSD databindings and all the good stuff in android?  (Coworker of mine thinks it's impossible to do, even with eclipse)  I don't have XE5 yet or I'd just try it.

Comment: @Peter: You can use `TXMLDocument` this way to work with XML files and exclude MS XML, which is what this question (and answer) are regarding. If you want a full discussion of what features are supported, I can't help you (especially in the space allowed for comments here). I'd see what `ADOM XML v4` supports by checking it's documentation; you should be able to find it via Google.