# Porting a win32 application (using Treeview and XMLDocument controls) to FireMonkey Mobile Application - Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I started the process of porting my win32 application over to a "FireMonkey Mobile Application – Delphi",.

The initial demo worked great until I tried to build it for Android. It seems the controls I used (TTreeview) and TXMLDocument, are only available for win32 and win64.  However, When I created a blank Firemonkey Mobile Application – Delphi    those two controls were allowed to be used. The Ttreeview control in Firemonkey is different then the one I used in my win 32 application.

So, what mobile plaform are those two controls applicable too (Windows Mobile?)?

I will need to find alternative Firemonkey compatible controls and objects to use for handling the tree display and for XML functionality for porting my app to Android. What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TXMLDocument` works fine on Android if you change the `DOMVendor`; by default, it uses MSXML. See [How do I stop the IDE from referencing Windows-specific XML units in my non-Windows project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20399229); that question has been previously (and very recently) asked and answered here.

The VCL `TTreeView` is a wrapper around a Windows Common Control, so it is only available on Windows platforms. Delphi does not (at least currently) support Windows Mobile as a target platform, so the only place the VCL `TTreeView` is available is in VCL-based Win32/Win64 applications. There is no "compatible FMX control" for the VCL `TTreeView`; you'll need to rewrite your code to work with the FMX `TTreeView` instead.

As far as your request for a recommendation for other components, requests for us to locate or recommend a tool, library, or other off-site resource are off-topic here. See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information, particularly the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It seems I may have jumped the gun.  I started a brand new balnk firemonkey mobile app and just placed a Treeview on it and it worked.  It is found here - FMX.TreeView. The XMLDocument needs to be replaced with a differnt vendor though - let me try that

Comment: In the form designer, if you hover over a control from the full list of controls, you will see a popup hint showing the platforms that the control will work on.